# Java: Parsing a string based on delimiter

Tags: java, string

I have to design an interface where it fetches data from machine and then plots it. I have already designed the fetch part and it fetches a string of format  `A&B@.13409$13400$13400$13386$13418$13427$13406$13383$13406$13412$13419$00000$00000$`

First five `A&B@.` characters are the identifier. Please note that the fifth character is `new line feed` i.e. ASCII `0xA`.

The function I have written -

```
   public static boolean checkStart(String str,String startStr){

       String Initials = str.substring(0,5);
       System.out.println("Here is start: " + Initials);       
       if (startStr.equals(Initials))
        return true;
        else
        return false;
     }
```

shows `Here is start: A&B@.` which is correct.

**Question 1:**
Why do we need to take `str.substring(0,5)` i.e. when I use `str.substring(0,4)` it shows only - `Here is start: A&B@` i.e. missing `new line feed`. Why is `New Line feed` making this difference.

Further to extract remaing string I have to use `s.substring(5,s.length())` instead of `s.substring(6,s.length())`

i.e. 
`s.substring(6,s.length())` produces `3409$13400$13400$13386$13418$13427$13406$13383$13406$13412$13419$00000$00000$` i.e missing the first char after the identifier `A&B@.`

**Question 2:**

My parsing function is:

```
public static String[] StringParser(String str,String del){
    String[] sParsed = str.split(del);
     for (int i=0; i<sParsed.length; i++) {
                     System.out.println(sParsed[i]);
              }
    return sParsed;
     }
```

It parses correctly for String `String s = "A&B@.13409/13400/13400/13386/13418/13427/13406/13383/13406/13412/13419/00000/00000/";` and calling the function as `String[] tokens = StringParser(rightChannelString,"/");`

But for String such as `String s = "A&B@.13409$13400$13400$13386$13418$13427$13406$13383$13406$13412$13419$00000$00000$"` , the call `String[] tokens = StringParser(rightChannelString,"$");` does not parse the string at all.

I am not able to figure out why this behaviour. Can any one please let me know the solution?

Thanks

Comment: What is `StringParser` doing? Does it use regular expressions?

Comment: @Henry Please see StringParser definition. Edited to show its functionality

Comment: @what'up The problem I asked is different, my code works for one scenario but does not work for another. Instead of negative vote .. solution would have helped me better. I am not a java expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1, the java API says that the substring method takes 2 parameters:

- beginIndex  the begin index, **inclusive**.
- endIndex  the end index, **exclusive**.

So in your example

```
String: A&B@.134
Index:  01234567
```

substring(0,4) = indexes 0 to 3 so A&B@, that's why you have to put 5 as the second parameter to recover your line delimiter.

Regarding question 2, I guess that the split method takes a regexp in parameter and $ is a special character. To match the dollar sign I guess you have to escape it with the \ character (as \ is a special char in strings so you must also escape it).

```
String[] tokens = StringParser(rightChannelString,"\\$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: review the description of `substring` in the documentation:

```
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.
The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the
character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring
is endIndex-beginIndex.
```

Q2: the `split` method takes a regular expression for the separator. `$` is a special character for regular expressions, it matches the end of the line.